# Default location of expo Mapview

Tags: react-native, maps, expo

I have a simple expo Map like this:

```
<MapView
    loadingEnabled
    ref = {c => (this.mapView = c)}
    style={ styles.mapStyle }
>
    {jobsToArray.map(function(item, i){
        return <MapView.Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={item}
        >
        </MapView.Marker>
    })}
    <MapViewDirections
        mode="DRIVING"
        optimizeWaypoints={true} //Make sure route is the fatest possible
        origin={this.state.myLocation.coords} //Start location = current location
        waypoints={jobsToArray} //Array of destinations to visit
        destination={jobsToArray[jobsToArray.length-1]} //Final destination
        onReady={result => {
            //Show entire map of waypoints with some padding
            this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
                edgePadding: {
                    right: width / 20,
                    bottom: height / 20,
                    left: width / 20,
                    top: height / 3
                }, animated: true }
            );
        }}
        onError={errorMessage => {
            // console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
        }}
    />
</MapView>`
```

The map animates to show all locations and it works well but I'm just a little peeved that the starting location of the map before my directions load is the middle of Africa (Shows the whole country though), then does a huge sweeping animation to a Suburb in Australia. Is there anyway to say, Show Australia (or an exact location) then zoom from there?

Ideally I would show the State our maps are working with then do a smaller zoom from there. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some simple code to add to `MapView`

`initialRegion={{
        latitude: -37.112146,
        longitude: 144.857483,
        latitudeDelta: 10,
        longitudeDelta: 10,
    }}`